# state is not getting updated for a new user in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, use-effect, use-state, asyncstorage

My app has a test sheet, if a user passes the test he is shown a passing screen and then the state is saved using asyncstorage. But the problem here is, let's say i have user A and user B and user A is currently logged in, he passed the test and the app shows him passing screen and the state is saved. Now user A logs out and user B logs in, he is a completely new user he has never given test before but my app has still saved the state for the user A and keeps showing passing screen even to the user B rather it should not.Can someone help me with this issue?

code:

```
import React ,{useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {View, Alert, Image, StyleSheet, Text, Modal, TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import Voice from 'react-native-voice';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';


import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
  const key = auth().currentUser.uid + "hasPassed"
  

export const hasPassed = async () => {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then(result => result != null ? JSON.parse(result) : undefined).catch(e => console.log(e))    
}

export const setHasPassed = async (newPassed) => {
    return AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify({hasPassed: newPassed})).catch(e => console.log(e))
}



export default alpht =({navigation}) => { 

 
 function Check() {
  if (results.includes(words[index])){
 
    Alert.alert('Correct!','You are learning so well!');
    
     if(index==7) {
      if(count<=5)
      {
           
        setHasPassed(true).then(() => setshowpass(true))
        //  setshowpass(true);
      }
      else{
        console.log(count)
        Alert.alert('fail','fail');
      }
    }
    if (index==7){
      setndis(true);
      setdis(true);
      setidis(true);
    }
    else{
   setndis(false);
   setdis(true);
   setidis(true);
    }
   
  }
  else{
    Alert.alert('Ops!','Looks like you went wrong somewhere. Try again!');
    setcount(count+1);
    
    setdis(true);
    setndis(true);
   
    if(count==5){
      Alert.alert('Restest', 'Looks like you had way too many mistakes!')
      setind(0);
      setcount(0);
      setdis(true);
    }
  }
}


  const words=['ceket', 'çilek', 'elma', 'fare', 'öğretmen', 'otobüs', 'şemsiye', 'uçak'];
  const [show, setshow]=useState('');
    const [showpass, setshowpass]=useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
     //console.log(auth().currentUser.uid);
        setshow(true);
      }, []);

      useEffect(() => {
        const getState = async () => {
          const result = await hasPassed()
          setshowpass(result ? result.hasPassed : false)
      }
      getState()
     
      }, []);

     
      console.log(auth().currentUser.uid)
      if (showpass === false) {

         
        // setshow(true)
        console.log('hey');
       return null
      }
return (
//... other code
)
}
```

my user logs out using auth().signOut() by the way!
It would be great if this issue gets solved i am dealing with it for the past 4,5 days now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the problem:

```js
const key = auth().currentUser.uid + "hasPassed"
  
export const hasPassed = async () => {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then(result => result != null ? JSON.parse(result) : undefined).catch(e => console.log(e))    
}

export const setHasPassed = async (newPassed) => {
    return AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify({hasPassed: newPassed})).catch(e => console.log(e))
}
```

`key` is defined at the top level, outside of the react lifecycle, and thus is subject to having stale values. `auth().currentUser` may change, the value of `key` will not (I think). Instead of storing key as a string, try storing it as a function:

```js
// every time getKey is called it will get a fresh instance of currentUser
const getKey = ()=>auth().currentUser.uid + "hasPassed"

export const hasPassed = async () => {
  return AsyncStorage.getItem(getKey()).
    then(result => result != null ? JSON.parse(result) : undefined).
    catch(e => console.log(e))    
}

export const setHasPassed = async (newPassed) => {
  return AsyncStorage.setItem(
    getKey(),
    JSON.stringify({hasPassed: newPassed})
  ).catch(e => console.log(e))
}
```

Comment: Yess!!!! It worked perfectly, i just had to refresh my database after updating the code like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what's going wrong in your code, but I believe that the piece of code in your useEffect is fetching the state of user A no matter who is logged in ( state persistence). try testing with user C. check out firebase state persistence in their official documentation. I hope I gave you some hints to solve this issue.